# TypeScript Setter's public property

Tags: typescript, setter

How can you set a public property for a setter item in JavaScript or TypeScript?

- or maybe other idea to implement like this:

```
var eventhandler =  function() {blah...}

class someClass {
   public set foo(value: any) {
        ...
   }
}

var bar: someClass;

bar.foo.onchange = eventhandler;

bar.foo.someProp = prop1;
```

Comment: hey Ali, welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the how to ask a good question guide. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You setter is for setting `foo`, but `bar.foo.someProp` **gets** `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create setters for on a class like this:

```js
class A {
    public aProp: string;

    public set propSetter(value: string) {
        this.aProp = value;
    }
}

new A().propSetter = 'abc';
```

The setter must however has a different name than the property since they will both end up as properties on the classes prototype.

You can see a fully working example [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20aProp%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20propSetter(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.aProp%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20A().propSetter%20%3D%20'abc'%3B).